# remove number from appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

I used this code to produce appendix

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
.
\clearpage
\appendix
\newpage
 
 \section{Appendix A}
  Stuff here 
  \section{Second Appendix}
  Stuff here 
  \section{Third Appendix}
  Stuff here 
\end{document}
```

and it appear in the follwoing format `.1 Appendix A` as shown in the picture[image: that]

how to get ride from `.1` so i will have only `Appendix A`

Also, how to make header tile for appendix take the section title on the left and page number on the right of the header

any suggestion?

Comment: Use `\section*{Appendix A}`

Comment: At least in the `book` class, appendices are more commonly typeset as unnumbered chapters; use `\chapter*{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in a book document class, appendices are written as chapters.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\pagestyle{headings}     %% for headings, for more customization, use fancyhdr package
\begin{document}
.
%\frontmatter   %% better to use this mark up
.
.
.
%\mainmatter    %% better to use this mark up
\begin{appendices}
 \chapter{Appendix A}
  \section{Stuff here}
  \clearpage
  Some
  \chapter{Second Appendix}
  Stuff here
  \chapter{Third Appendix}
  Stuff here
\end{appendices}

%%backmatter      %% better to use this mark up
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]